# HISTFILE env var unset within programs. Can I access it in any way?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, command-history

When I try to access the "HISTFILE" env var within a program, it isn't there

```
$ echo $HISTFILE
/Users/drewgross/.bash_history
$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['HISTFILE']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'HISTFILE'
```

But if I set it directly, it is:

```
$ HISTFILE=wat python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['HISTFILE']
'wat'
```

It seems to be hidden for some reason. Why is that? Is there any way to access this var within my programs?

Comment: That explains somewhat, but doesn't explain how to access HISTFILE in a program (if thats even possible)

Comment: @Drew: You need to export the shell variable for it to become an environment variable, which will then be inherited by child processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to either type **export HISTFILE** on the command line prior to starting the python interpreter (or running your python script) or add **export HISTFILE** to your .bashrc file so that it is automatically exported when you login.